# Why can't I archive a Xamarin.Forms iOS application?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

We are building a Xamarin.Forms app on windows machines using Visual Studio 2019.  We have created the developer provisioning certificates, distribution certificates, developer provisioning profiles, and distribution profiles.

We pair Visual Studio to a Mac and can deploy our applications onto iOS devices.  When in xCode on the Mac, we can see the provisioning profiles are installed.

When we look in Visual Studio, at Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts, we can see everything looks like it should:

[image]

But we can't right-click->Archive our iOS project.  It always appears grayed out.

[image]

Our project is set to Release and iPhone for the Active solution platform.  What else needs to be done to get the archive functionality working for iOS projects inside visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, after deleting all bin and obj folders and moving just the proj and sln (don't copy .git, .vs etc) to mac I was able to publish using vs for mac.
note: I had to update vs for mac, otherwise it wanted to use application loader, which is no longer supported for xcode 11.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or higher to be able to archive iOS projects.

Alternatively, you can manually upload the IPA file from a mac using this from the command line:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file "/Users/*****/*****/******.iOS.ipa" --username "Your Apple ID" --password "app-specific password"
```

Comment: I found out what the issue was. You need to have Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 and higher to be able to archive iOS projects.

Comment: Same here, after update VS 2019 from 16.2 to 16.3, it worked. Thanx!